# Unable to start mysql on ubuntu

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I'm trying to mysql, but I'm receiving this error:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 start
 * Starting web server apache2                                                                                                                                                                               * 
ubuntu@ip-172-31-19-47:/var/www/html/anunciolocal$ sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start
 * /etc/init.d/mysql: ERROR: The partition with /var/lib/mysql is too full!
```

When I checked my memory:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-19-47:~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            996M   12K  996M   1% /dev
tmpfs           201M  344K  200M   1% /run
/dev/xvda1       16G   15G  307M  98% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none           1001M     0 1001M   0% /run/shm
none            100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
overflow        1.0M  992K   32K  97% /tmp
```

How do I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running it this way

```
sudo service mysql stop
sudo service mysql start
```

Comment: `sudo service mysql restart` can this be done instead? What would be the difference?

Comment: Why would you expect this to make a difference? On any reasonable system which supports both `service` and `/etc/init.d`, they should be equivalent -- there's no reason why using `service` should magically make more disk space appear.

Answer (score 1):

/etc/init.d/mysql: ERROR: The partition with /var/lib/mysql is too full!

this is why you cant start mysql

please clear /dev/xvda1  the disk has no enough space

Comment: please go through:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/482923/mysql-error-the-partition-with-var-lib-mysql-is-too-full